# Admob ads adding to previous screen when using back button?

Tags: android, admob, ondestroy

Just installed admob tonight and works fine except for one issue. When
using the back button, the ads add to the main screen or last page
your were on. Lets see if I can explain. When app is open it has one
ad showing I visit a list menu item then hit the back button it adds
one ad to the page I was just on, now I have two. Do it again now have
three..... etc. It will continue to do it until the screen is full.
Reopen the app it starts at one again. I refresh the screen it reverts
to one again. Being a new not sure what you would want from me to help
solve this issue, but please ask.

I would assume this would have something to do with it?

```
//onDestroy
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    adView.destroy();
    super.onDestroy();
    //BT_debugger.showIt(activityName + ":onDestroy");  
}
```

Android 3.2
GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-4.3.1.jar

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where are you first calling admod? In the layout.xml? onCreate? or onResume?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?  //**adview (after onResume, before onDestroy)

// Create Admob View
    adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, Config.ADMOB_PUBLISHER_ID);

Comment: Where and when are you initializing your adView? It sounds like it's a problem there.

Comment: I would try moving that to the `onCreate` Method. The `onCreate` method is only called once with the Activity is first loaded. The `onResume` will be called each time the activity is shown. Also, I believe `onDestroy` is only called when your app closes, not when you leave the activity.

Comment: //onResume
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
       super.onResume();
       //BT_debugger.showIt(activityName + ":onResume");
       
    // Create Admob View
       adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, Config.ADMOB_PUBLISHER_ID);

       // Lookup LinearLayout
       LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.admob_main);

    // Add the adView to it
       layout.addView(adView);

       // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
       adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
       
   }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this:

```
//onResume
@Override 
public void onResume() { 
    super.onResume(); 
    //BT_debugger.showIt(activityName + ":onResume"); 
    // Create Admob View 
    adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, Config.ADMOB_PUBLISHER_ID); 
    // Lookup LinearLayout 
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.admob_main); 
    // Add the adView to it 
    layout.addView(adView); 
    // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad 
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest()); 
}
```

Move these lines to the the `onCreate` Method and delete them from the `onResume`

```
adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, Config.ADMOB_PUBLISHER_ID); 
// Lookup LinearLayout 
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.admob_main); 
// Add the adView to it 
layout.addView(adView); 
// Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad 
adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

Comment: Worked like a Champ! Thanks for the help @woodsy